# Windows' menus are unreadable

Tags: windows

This is a problem that has occurred since I had Windows 8 (that came with this laptop). I upgraded to 8.1, and today I've upgraded to Windows 10 and the problem *still* persists.

[image]

As you can see, the "Medium Icons" option is selected, but the actual bullet point is barely visible. Also, there are arrows on the expandable option groups and they are downright *invisible*. What is wrong with my computer?

Comment: I guess, check those settings: `reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors"` and `reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Colors"`